# Unbalanced Parenthesis correction

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm prepping for a coding interview, and am examining the task of correcting unbalanced parentheses. The finger tree seems to be the right data structure.
As a proof of concept I've used `Data.Sequence` to test my idea. If this is the right direction to go, I'll write more specialized finger tree code.
The code works on the few test cases I have tried. Feedback appreciated.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
module Parenthesis where
import BasicPrelude hiding (concat,null,empty)

import Data.Sequence hiding (length)
import Data.Foldable hiding (length,null)

data Debit = RP

balanceParens :: String -> String
balanceParens str = go str [] empty
  where
    go :: String -> [Debit] -> Seq Char -> String
    go [] [] (null -> True) = []
    go [] [] parens = Data.Foldable.toList parens
    go ('(':xs) [] (null -> True) = go xs [RP] (singleton '(')
    go (')':xs) [] (null -> True) = go xs [] (fromList "()")
    go ('(':xs) debit parens = go xs (RP:debit) (parens |> '(')
    go (')':xs) [] parens = go xs [] corrected
      where corrected = ('(' <| parens) |> ')'
    go (')':xs) (RP:debit) parens = go xs debit (parens |> ')')
    go (_:xs) debit parens = go xs debit parens
    go [] (RP:debit) parens = go [] debit (parens |> ')')
```

example:

```
balanceParens "))("
"(())()"
balanceParens ")))"
"((()))"
```

Comment: This code won't compile. You didn't give the definition of `RP`, and `BasicPrelude` needs `-XNoImplicitPrelude`.

Comment: Also, why is `balanceParens "))("` `"(())()"` and not `"()()()"`? Why is the first more favourable than the latter?

Answer (score 2):

Each case containing `null -> True` is subsumed by another. Your recursion is shaped like `foldl`:

```
balanceParens :: String -> String
balanceParens = finish $ foldl foo ([], empty) where
  finish (debit, parens) = Data.Foldable.toList parens ++ [')' | RP <- debit]
  foo (   debit, parens) '(' = (RP:debit,         parens  |> '(')
  foo (      [], parens) ')' = (      [], ('(' <| parens) |> ')')
  foo (RP:debit, parens) ')' = (   debit,         parens  |> ')')
  foo (   debit, parens) _   = (   debit,         parens        )
```